# readdir is returning lots of all-0xFF 8.3 names from fat32 filesystem

Tags: c, esp32, readdir, fat32, esp-idf

I'm working on an ESP32 platform with IDF 4.1, using code like this:

```
struct dirent * dirent;
while((dirent = readdir(dir)) != nullptr) {
   ESP_LOGI("ConfigServer", "Found %s, id %d, type %d", dirent->d_name, dirent->d_ino, dirent->d_type);
   if(dirent->d_name[0] == '\377') {
      ++invalid_ctr;
   } else {
      // do something with the file info
   }
}
closedir(dir);
```

I had to add the bit where `invalid_ctr` is incremented, because I started getting loads of iterations where `dirent->d_name` was `"\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377.\377\377\377"` (rendered as inverse-video "?" characters in my terminal).  The code not shown involves feeding that name to `stat()`, which would return the same values as the last valid file encountered.  The log entry would look like this:

```
 I (608261) ConfigServer: Found ��������.���, id 0, type 2
```

Type 2 represents a directory.  This is happening on a partition on the onboard flash, formatted by the IDF library's "format if mount failed" option at mount.  So perhaps my assumption of FAT32 is invalid.  I do know that IDF uses FatFs internally.

Is this indicative of an error on the filesystem?  Is it expected to need to filter out such trash on a typical iteration with `readdir()`?

Comment: Q: Are you able to to do a "DIR" or equivalent on the filesystem?  If so, are you able to correlate a "filename" (in DIR) to a "garbage entry" (in readdir())?

Comment: Could be that the slots belong to the previous slot, adding extra space for long file names or extendend attributes. Or they are just 'not in use' (IIRC the first byte of the name would then be 0xf6)

Comment: The code that stored the directory entry to disk might have been written to avoid a couple of Microsoft VFAT patents that relate to storing *both* a long and a short name for the same item. (The patents can be worked around either by storing only a short name, or by storing a long name with an invalid short name.)

Comment: @wildplasser The garbage entries all have 0xFF as the first byte.  As I recall, deallocated FAT entries (deleted files) have a tilde in the first slot.  In either case, I would expect `readdir` to skip over that automatically.

Comment: @IanAbbott Interesting hypothesis.  This is all part of simple web server code that allows me to upload files into this partition (and delete them) via a web browser.  Some names fit 8.3 and some do not; the garbage didn't start immediately with the use of a long filename, but there could be some combination of adds and deletes that eventually created the problem.

Comment: @paulsm4 By pulling the image off the chip and mounting it on my linux host, I see only the expected file entries.  No garbage. HOWEVER...trying to interact with any of those files produces garbage results, as if the FAT entries are mangled in some way.  `mount` thinks it's vfat, but IIRC vfat gets used for several flavors of FAT.  It also occurs to me that wear-leveling in the IDF code might be doing something that `mount` doesn't understand.

Comment: More details about DOS LFNs: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_of_the_FAT_file_system#VFAT, http://www.fysnet.net/longfile.htm

Comment: @IanAbbott the ms patent was invalidated by Linus Torvald's deposition regarding a newsgroup discussion of the prior art in the minux fs. Linux has rejected workaround patches because they are not needed anymore. Minux published the technique before the ms patent was filed

Comment: See: https://www.wired.com/2012/03/ms-patent/

Comment: So, I've coded to suppress the garbage, and log the number of garbage entries that got suppressed.  So far, I haven't encountered any other issues with the filesystem...but it's noteworthy that the number of valid LFNs in the directory doesn't seem to affect the number of garbage entries; there are always 122.  Oh well, as long as it works...

Comment: @BrianA.Henning Have you been able to solve this other than ignoring the garbage files?

Comment: @A6SE No.  I haven't given it any further attention.

Comment: @BrianA.Henning After thorough research, I've decided to switch from FAT based wear-levelled filesystem to LittleFS, as FAT is fragile and prone to power loss failures (as suggested here [https://espressif-docs.readthedocs-host ... power-loss](https://espressif-docs.readthedocs-hosted.com/projects/espressif-esp-faq/en/latest/software-framework/storage/fatfs.html#how-to-improve-the-damage-to-fatfs-file-system-caused-by-accidental-power-loss)). I haven't had any problems with garbage files since.

Answer (score 1):

The FAT component in ESP IDF has support for long file names disabled by default. Run `idf.py menuconfig`, then "Component config → FAT Filesystem support → Long filename support" to enable it.

Comment: Good suggestion, but mine is already set to "Long filename buffer on stack".