# get exactly same filename in directory properly

Tags: c, string, file, directory

I would like to get exactly same filename from C

```
    DIR *d;
    struct dirent *dir;
    d = opendir("/sdcard");
    if (d)
    {
        while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL)
        {
            printf("%s\n", dir->d_name);
        }
    }
```

I'm using this way. However I have a problem get numbers in filename

- Actual filename: DATA_20000.TXT
- When I got filename: DATA_2~1.TXT

and other numbers were same like this

- Actual filename: DATA_21234.TXT
- When I got filename: DATA_2~3.TXT

How could I get exactly same number from filename?

Comment: What platform are you running on? What filesystem is the sdcard formatted with? Those look like Windows short filenames.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Now I'm reading files in ESP32 with freeRTOS. I made files in Window for testing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69529278/readdir-is-returning-lots-of-all-0xff-8-3-names-from-fat32-filesystem may be relevant.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [readdir is returning lots of all-0xFF 8.3 names from fat32 filesystem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69529278/readdir-is-returning-lots-of-all-0xff-8-3-names-from-fat32-filesystem)